# Failed: javascript error: circular reference

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Im running protractor , chromedriver_76.0.3809.12 ,selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59 , google chrome Version 76.0.3809.100.
I have code have always worked. Today I had this error "Chrome version must be between 71 and 75 error"  after some research I found that this could help "npm i webdriver-manager@latest". Since then I keep getting "- Failed: javascript error: circular reference" in multiple parts of the code. (Code that worked)

```
    this.goToTab = function (locator, elem, nextStep, promise) {
        console.log('go to tab');
        that.waitForScreenToFade(that.sideMenu, function () {
            that.sideMenu.click().then(function () {
                browser.isElementPresent(locator).then(function (present) {
                    console.log(present);
                    if (present) {
                        element(locator).click().then(function () {
                            that.selectMenu(elem, nextStep, promise);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        that.selectMenu(elem, nextStep, promise);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

" that.sideMenu.click()" fails

Just to clarify, my isse is NOT about the chrome versions or driver version. My issue is "javascript error: circular reference" when running code that have always worked

Comment: Please check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493979/5324105