# Why dynamic drop down throwing "javascript error: circular reference"?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This is a 3 step code written to open the website spicejet.com and then select delhi in the source dropdown button. But it is throwing an error as "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: circular reference". Chrome opens but then delhi is not selected.

There is no issue with jar files etc. as other code is working.

public class DynamicDropDown {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Chrome Driver 76.0\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://spicejet.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\a[@value='DEL'")).click();


}
```

}

error message: org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: circular reference

Comment: Its fixed in chromedriver version 76.0.3809.126 . Update the chromedriver.exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492625/chromedriver-76-breaks-my-test-suite-javascript-error-circular-reference/57493979#57493979